# Keeping org-mode outline after reverting buffer

Tags: org-mode

Is there any option or other customization to keep the outline of an org-mode buffer (uncollapsed parts of the tree) after the buffer has been
reverted (org-mode 9.0.1, emacs 25.3.2)? In my case only the top
headings are displayed after reverting. This is quite annoying and
time-consuming in a setup, where one constantly switches between git
branches e.g.

Comment: Look at `org-startup-folded`'s docstring, which might be the variable you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help in this case. See below for the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer was provided on the mailing list:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-01/msg00336.html

Quotation of the relevant part of that message:

> Org provides two functions to save and restore visibility (and a macro
>   that does both, but isn't useful in your case):
>   `org-outline-overlay-data` and `org-set-outline-overlay-data`.
>
> You may want to use them within `before-revert-hook` and
>   `after-revert-hook`.

The following is useful for implementing it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666862/org-mode-go-back-from-sparse-tree-to-previous-visibility/44158824#44158824

---

Note that the functions `org-outline-overlay-data` and `org-set-outline-overlay-data` do not exist anymore in Orgmode 9.2.

Citation of the incompatible changes of Orgmode 9.2:

> Removed commands and functions
>
> ### `org-outline-overlay-data`
>
> Use `org-save-outline-visibility` instead.
>
> ### `org-set-outline-overlay-data`
>
> Use `org-save-outline-visibility` instead.

### Possible Implementation

There follows Elisp code that preserves the outline state of headings over `revert-buffer`. It includes the definitions of `org-outline-overlay-data` and `org-set-outline-overlay-data` that have been deleted from Orgmode 9.2.

```el
(defun org-outline-overlay-data (&optional use-markers)
  "Return a list of the locations of all outline overlays.
These are overlays with the `invisible' property value `outline'.
The return value is a list of cons cells, with start and stop
positions for each overlay.
If USE-MARKERS is set, return the positions as markers."
  (let (beg end)
    (org-with-wide-buffer
     (delq nil
       (mapcar (lambda (o)
             (when (eq (overlay-get o 'invisible) 'outline)
               (setq beg (overlay-start o)
                 end (overlay-end o))
               (and beg end (> end beg)
                (if use-markers
                (cons (copy-marker beg)
                      (copy-marker end t))
                  (cons beg end)))))
           (overlays-in (point-min) (point-max)))))))

(defun org-set-outline-overlay-data (data)
  "Create visibility overlays for all positions in DATA.
DATA should have been made by `org-outline-overlay-data'."
  (org-with-wide-buffer
   (org-show-all)
   (dolist (c data) (org-flag-region (car c) (cdr c) t 'outline))))

(defvar-local my-org-outline-state nil
  "Place for saving org outline state before reverting the buffer.")

(put 'my-org-outline-state 'permanent-local t)

(defun my-org-save-outline-state ()
  "Save org outline state in `my-org-outline-state'.
It can be recovered afterwards with `my-org-recover-outline-state'."
  (setq my-org-outline-state (org-outline-overlay-data t)))

(defun my-org-restore-outline-state ()
  "Save org outline state in `my-org-outline-state'.
It can be recovered afterwards with `my-org-recover-outline-state'."
  (when my-org-outline-state
    (org-set-outline-overlay-data my-org-outline-state)
    (setq my-org-outline-state nil)))

(defun my-org-install-save-outline-state ()
  "Configure org to preserve the outline state at revert-buffer."
  (add-hook 'before-revert-hook #'my-org-save-outline-state nil t)
  (add-hook 'after-revert-hook #'my-org-restore-outline-state nil t))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-install-save-outline-state)
```