# Org-mode 9.2:Can' t find the error on my dot emacs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I recently update my `org` to the version `9.2`
(to be precise: `Org mode version 9.2.3 (9.2.3-4-g6ec402-elpaplus @ /home/nanounanue/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20190408/`)

I did it because I replaced the `ob-ipython` with `emacs-jupyter` (more stable, more features and now I am very happy)

Now, I am experimenting the following hiccups:

(a) When I try to insert a code block using the new keybinding `C-c C-,` I got:

```
Warning (org):
Please update the entries of `org-structure-template-alist'.

In Org 9.2 the format was changed from something like

("s" "#+BEGIN_SRC ?\n#+END_SRC")

to something like

("s" . "src")

Please refer to the documentation of `org-structure-template-alist'.

The following entries must be updated:

(("n" "#+BEGIN_NOTES\n?\n#+END_NOTES")
("Q" "#+BEGIN_SRC sql-mode ?\n\n#+END_SRC" "#+BEGIN_SRC sql-mode ?\n\n#+END_SRC"))
```

I searched in my =.emacs= and I don't find those lines, actually my templates are:

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("el" . "src emacs-lisp"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("sh" . "src shell"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("Q" . "src sql"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("py" . "src jupyter-python"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("md" . "src markdown"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("sr" . "src R"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("l" . "src lisp"))

(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
'("cl" . "src clojure"))
```

So, I am kind of lost here.

(b) My `sql` babel blocks now throw the following error everytime that the cursor enters the block

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp 5434)
#f(compiled-function (elem) #<bytecode 0x1563983c7e95>)((:dbport . 5434))
mapconcat(#f(compiled-function (elem) #<bytecode 0x1563983c7e95>) ((:results . "drawer table replace") (:exports . "both") (:cmdline . "-q") (:eval . "no-export") (:database . "food") (:dbpassword . "some_password") (:dbuser . "food_user") (:dbport . 5434) (:dbhost . "0.0.0.0") (:engine . "postgresql") (:tangle . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) " ")
org-eldoc-get-src-header()
org-eldoc-documentation-function()
eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1feb98d89639>)()
apply(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1feb98d89639>) nil)
timer-event-handler([t 0 0 100000 t #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1feb98d89639>) nil idle 0])
```

(c) If I try to refresh the headers of an org-mode buffer using `C-c C-c` I got the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-outline-overlay-data)
org-outline-overlay-data(use-markers)
org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
#f(compiled-function (cmd &optional record-flag keys special) "Execute CMD as an editor command.\nCMD must be a symbol that satisfies the `commandp' predicate.\nOptional second arg RECORD-FLAG non-nil\nmeans unconditionally put this command in the variable `command-history'.\nOtherwise, that is done only if an arg is read using the minibuffer.\nThe argument KEYS specifies the value to use instead of (this-command-keys)\nwhen reading the arguments; if it is nil, (this-command-keys) is used.\nThe argument SPECIAL, if non-nil, means that this command is executing\na special event, so ignore the prefix argument and don't clear it." #<bytecode 0x1feb98d60d25>)(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil nil)
ad-Advice-command-execute(#f(compiled-function (cmd &optional record-flag keys special) "Execute CMD as an editor command.\nCMD must be a symbol that satisfies the `commandp' predicate.\nOptional second arg RECORD-FLAG non-nil\nmeans unconditionally put this command in the variable `command-history'.\nOtherwise, that is done only if an arg is read using the minibuffer.\nThe argument KEYS specifies the value to use instead of (this-command-keys)\nwhen reading the arguments; if it is nil, (this-command-keys) is used.\nThe argument SPECIAL, if non-nil, means that this command is executing\na special event, so ignore the prefix argument and don't clear it." #<bytecode 0x1feb98d60d25>) org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
apply(ad-Advice-command-execute #f(compiled-function (cmd &optional record-flag keys special) "Execute CMD as an editor command.\nCMD must be a symbol that satisfies the `commandp' predicate.\nOptional second arg RECORD-FLAG non-nil\nmeans unconditionally put this command in the variable `command-history'.\nOtherwise, that is done only if an arg is read using the minibuffer.\nThe argument KEYS specifies the value to use instead of (this-command-keys)\nwhen reading the arguments; if it is nil, (this-command-keys) is used.\nThe argument SPECIAL, if non-nil, means that this command is executing\na special event, so ignore the prefix argument and don't clear it." #<bytecode 0x1feb98d60d25>) org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

All these behaviour showed up with the upgrade to `org 9.2`. Could someone give me pointers or help?

(Originally posted in https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/bcjl8u/help_cant_find_the_errors/)

Comment: The structure template error might also stem from not yet updated packages. The Elisp-code from [another answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48974/2370) gives you the old structure templates back. It coexists with the new format. It just does the right thing instead of issuing an error. Make sure you inject the code as early as possible in your init files.

Comment: Could it be that once upon a time you byte-compiled your init file. That is a no-go! Remove `~/.emacs.elc` if it exists.

Comment: This should be closed as too broad. You've asked two lengthy questions in one. Please delete this question and ask two separate questions (split it in two).

Comment: As usual, rather than try to deal with your entire init file when debugging, narrow it down. Do a binary search to narrow it down by commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16 etc. of it. If the answer is not obvious after you've narrowed the causing code down then post a question with the narrowed problematic code. That helps others help you, and it makes the Q&A more useful for other users who might have a similar problem/question.

Comment: @Drew The right title for this question would be: "What is wrong with the version 9.2 of Org-mode." I already answered two questions [there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48974/2370) and [there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/keeping-org-mode-outline-after-reverting-buffer/38212#38212) about the incompatible changes in Org 9.2. Now, both problems hit user nanounanue in a way which leaves an not so much experienced user no chance to do anything about it.

Comment: @Drew This is the first case I saw that these problems hit the user indirectly through third-party packages. (BTW: Please do not understand me wrong: It is true, I'm a bit frustrated about incompatible changes in Org mode. Nevertheless, I very much appreciate the volunteer work on Org mode. It is great stuff and I use it for my daily work.) On second thought I find the title of this question very much appropriate. It reflexes how helpless a not so much experienced user is facing those problems.

Comment: @Drew the question was already answered. Could you remove the hold?

Comment: Done. Please consider updating the question to maybe make it a bit clearer and more useful for others in combination with the answer.

Comment: Most importantly, shorten it by focusing on a single problem (presumably the `org-structure-template-alist').

Comment: @Drew Thank you. I totally agree, but let me explain my rationale, I though that all the problems were related (my fault or my ignorance or both). The problem with dividing the question now, is that Tobias already answer all  of it, even the mainteiner of ob-sql fixed the problem in his/her repo. So, If I edit the question, all of it will be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ob-sql-mode` package](https://github.com/nikclayton/ob-sql-mode/blob/master/ob-sql-mode.el) is not updated for org-mode 9.2 yet. There you find as of 2019-04-20 [the following lines in master](https://github.com/nikclayton/ob-sql-mode/blob/49dac3b64f9eaebe9d406e398f95a40b2993e6d0/ob-sql-mode.el#L158-L163):

```el
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("sql-mode" . sql))
     (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
                  `(,org-babel-sql-mode-template-selector
                    "#+BEGIN_SRC sql-mode ?\n\n#+END_SRC"
                    "#+BEGIN_SRC sql-mode ?\n\n#+END_SRC"))))
```

Thereby the value of `org-babel-sql-mode-template-selector` is `Q` as the second update-requirement in your first error message says.

To cure this special problem you can add back the old behavior of `org-structure-template-alist` with the [compatibility Elisp code given at the answer to another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48974/2370). Note that `eval-after-load` adds its form argument at the end of `after-load-alist`. To load the compatibility Elisp code before the package `ob-sql-mode` is loaded you must call the compatibility code before `ob-sql-mode`. If you do not explicitly load `ob-sql-mode` in your init file it should be sufficient to put the compatibility Elisp code into your init file.

Yor error case `(b)` is also connected to sql org babel blocks (that way it receives the eldoc-messages). If you are lucky, the error will disappear after re-compiling the package directory.

[Lunaryhorn recommends the following user-input for recompiling all packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24735377/2708138):

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)`

That may take a while...

---

I also found a reference for your `note` block update message:
It seems to be hydra and [there is already a fix](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/issues/308#issuecomment-451566828) there. If you have installed `hydra` you should update the `hydra` package.

---

Now to your problem (c).
That is also an already known problem.
The functions `org-outline-overlay-data` and `org-set-outline-overlay-data` have been removed from org-mode without adequate replacement.

My edit of [another answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38212/2370) shows you what you need to get these functions back.

Note that the [the proposed `org-save-outline-visibility`](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html#outline-container-org7f738b5) is not a solution to all problems that occur because of the removal of `org-outline-overlay-data` and `org-set-outline-overlay-data`. For an instance `org-save-outline-visibility` cannot be used with `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook`.

Comment: For the `ob-sql-mode` problem, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/nikclayton/ob-sql-mode/issues/7).

Comment: Thanks for the ob-sql-mode issue, I've just committed a fix, which should show up on MELPA shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much! After following your advice I am getting this warning: `Warning (emacs): Duplicated keys in ‘org-structure-template-alist’ and ‘org-tempo-keywords-alist’`

Comment: @nanounanue You get duplicated entries with your setup. For an instance `Q` is defined in the `ob-sql-mode` package and in your init file. You can ignore those warning if everything works like expected. Usually the first definition is used if some key is doubly defined.

Comment: @nanounanue I removed the phrase "At least a partial answer" since I believe that I address all problems from your question now. Do you agree? Does everything work now as good as possible with the new Org version?

Comment: I totally agree @Tobias